# Get binary data in byte[] array from a url in android (Flatbuffers)

Tags: java, android, url, android-volley, flatbuffers

My code so far

```
Globals.GET(Globals.GET_WORDS_URL, new Globals.VolleyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            byte[] bytes = result.getBytes();
            loadFlatBuffer(bytes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String result) {

        }
    });
```

I am getting it as String, then converting it into byte array.

**What I want**

I want it in **Byte[] array** instead of **string**

**Its a .bin file getting as bytes from a url**

Answer (score 4):

If you use Volley, for your requirement, I suggest that you create a custom request as the following

```
public class BinaryRequest extends Request<byte[]>
```

You can find more details about create a custom request at

> [Google's training documentation - Implementing a Custom Request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html)

Then inside your app, use as the following:

```
    BinaryRequest binaryRequest = new BinaryRequest(method, url, new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
                //do something...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //do something...
            }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is the first parameter "method" for?

Comment: It's an integer, 0 is GET, 1 is POST :)

Comment: You can refer to the source code of my BinaryRequest.java at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ivmSFu7UqZSVlVbXFBdWpNdjA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No...It not getting into the response method

Comment: Either onResponse or onError should be called, pls post your new code or if your server Url published in Internet, post it so that I can check more.

Comment: here this is what I am doing...http://frogermcs.github.io/flatbuffers-in-android-introdution/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97058/discussion-between-johnrao07-and-bnk).

Comment: Hi! I could not find in your above link any code relating to Volley. Can you post more code that you use? If the ".bin file Url" is Internet published, pls post it so that I can check.